# Related to umbraco forms

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, umbraco8, umbraco-blog

how to create plugin same as umbracoforms with same functionality?
-If we add custom Fields from database in to umbraco backend custom section and it will reflect in to frontend same as umbraco forms can anybody guide me related to this ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please update your question to add more details to your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replicate something like that, I'll suggest you to start based on a already made code base.

Take a look at this project for AngularJS: [forms generator AngularJS](https://mackentoch.github.io/easyFormGenerator/)